# rails refresh page on json response

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, dropzone.js

I am trying to upload a file using [dropzone](http://sudharti.github.io/articles/dropzone-rails/). When the file is uploaded, I want to redirect the page to root url. When I upload the file, the request is sent and the response is in json format. I have in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json{ render :json => { :location => root_url, :flash => {:success => "The file was uploaded successfully"} }}
end
```

Can please anyone help me with what is wrong with my respond_to block?

Answer (score 2):

This json response will not in itself redirect, as it responds with json to (presumably) an ajax request. When the response comes back, the client will need to do something with that response, such as set window.location to the  :location attribute.

ie in the success callback of the dropzone request